# failed to instantiating chaincode in IBM Blockchain Platform

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain, chaincode

Basically, I am following this

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain/howto?topic=blockchain-ibp-console-smart-contracts#ibp-console-smart-contracts-connect-to-SDK

to deploy a smart contract from my local network to IBM Blockchain Platform. Everything went smoothly until step four. I got an error indicating that something is wrong with my container.

I googled for a while and the most promising answer inferring that there might be some problems on web docker.

Here is the description for the error:

An error occurred during instantiation.

grpc payload is empty: error starting container: error starting container: Post http://localhost:2375/build?t=dev-jdoe-papercontract-0.0.4-c9f772dd033af7a0d2fa0b7aafb268a2f2d8045143cb4344d3356fbe72999ee0: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Failed to pull ibmblockchain/fabric-javaenv:amd64-v1.4.1: API error (404): pull access denied for ibmblockchain/fabric-javaenv, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

This is what it looks like on my screen:

[image]

It would be rather helpful if someone can tell me how to fix it. Thanks a lot in advance.

---

a little update: I tried to use JS instead of Java to write the smart contract, the same error popped out during the instantiating step.

Comment: At this time Java chaincode isn't supported on IBM Blockchain platform. I tried to find this in the official documentation but couldn't so if the information is there it isn't obvious.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Let me make some experiments with JS chaincodes.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem of language at this moment, because I used JS and the same error jumps out. Maybe some other things goes off the road?

Comment: for java you got this message `Failed to pull ibmblockchain/fabric-javaenv:amd64-v1.4.1` and that is the indicator that java chaincode is not supported. You should not get this message if you are writing javascript chaincode and specifying the language as `node`

Comment: @david_k you are right, I reboot the network and use JS to write the smart contract, and it worked. Thanks!